# Pass User-Agent and client ip to Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Kind of fresh to this:

I have a very simple Lambda function that is trying to do a look up against a database with the client/user ip address. I am not passing the IP address from the client but want to pull it from the Request headers of the API Gateway call.

For the POST method of the Resource I am mapping these HTTP Request Headers:

- HTTP_CLIENT_IP (not sure if this is sufficient)
- User_Agent

I have one Body Mapping Template for "application/json" for the Integration Request:

`{ 
"source_ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
"user_agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent"`
}

When testing the POST method from the AWS API Gateway console I set the HTTP_CLIENT_IP to a valid private address and the User-Agent to "test". These are my results:

From PostMan my results are:

"`{\"isBase64Encoded\":false,\"statusCode\":200,\"headers\":`{\"Access-Control - Allow - Origin\":\"*\"`},\"body\":`{\"badIP\":false,\"ipIsNull\":true,\"ip\":null`}`}"

The results from the AWS console are not really a concern but the results from PostMan are!

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Below is the very small Lambda function:

```
"use strict";

console.log('Loading function');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => `{
     var loc = getGeoLocByIP(event.source_ip, event.user_agent, context);
     callback(null, JSON.stringify(loc));
`};

function getGeoLocByIP(clientIp, userAgent, event) `{
    var maxmind = require('maxmind');
    if (maxmind.validate(clientIp)) `{
       var fs = require('fs');
       var dbLoc = 'data/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'; 

       if (fs.existsSync(dbLoc)) `{
           var cityLookup = maxmind.openSync(dbLoc);
           var lkupres = cityLookup.get(clientIp);
           cityName = lkupres.city.names.en;
           var response = `{
              "isBase64Encoded": false,
              "statusCode": 200,
              "headers": `{
                 "Access-Control - Allow - Origin": "*"
              `},
              "body": `{
                 "cityName": cityName,
                 "client_ip": clientIP,
                 "user_agent": userAgent
              `}
           `};
           return response;
       `} else `{
        console.warn('db file does not exist: ' + dbLoc);
       `}
    `} else `{
      if (clientIp != null) `{
          var response = `{
            "isBase64Encoded": false,
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": `{
                "Access-Control - Allow - Origin": "*"
            `},
            "body": `{
                "badIP": true,
                "ipIsNull": false,
                "ip": clientIp
            `}
        `};
    `} else `{
        var response = `{
            "isBase64Encoded": false,
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": `{
                "Access-Control - Allow - Origin": "*"
            `},
            "body": `{
                "badIP": false,
                "ipIsNull": true,
                "ip" : null
            `}
        `};
    `}
    return response;
`}
```

`}
}

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of backticks around the brackets (`{` and `}`) in your code that may or may not be the cause of the problem. Backticks are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in JavaScript.

Assuming that your function is syntactically correct, you *should* be receiving the `source_ip` and `user_agent` in your Lambda function as your mapping expression is correct.

Check the log output of your Lambda function as well, that may lead to identifying the problem.

Also, just a heads-up. You're passing the `context` variable from your handler to your `getGeoLocByIp` and calling it `event`. This could lead to confusion. Although, you're not referencing the `event-context` anywhere so you can remove it.

Comment: the backticks were my attempt to provide well formatted markdown, fail.  as for the event and context I was swapping back and forth between both to see if I could discover where the values were. I will remove it.   thanks for the tip.